# SOAP Request to local WCF Service results in "InvalidSecurity Error"

Tags: wcf, soap, soapui

We've got a WCF service with `BasicHttpBinding` and tested it via SoapUI.
My co-worker can post the requests just fine, but on my machine I get the following error returned:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <s:Body>
      <s:Fault>
         <faultcode xmlns:a="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">a:InvalidSecurity</faultcode>
         <faultstring xml:lang="de-AT">The caller was not authenticated by the service.</faultstring>
      </s:Fault>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

I'm pretty clueless as to why it doesn't work on my machine. IIS Settings are the same, too. A typical "It works on MY machine!" problem...

Comment: Can you check the system clock where application is running to see if it is running slow than current time.